# Change the default Button-Label on android Keyboard

Tags: java, android, button, label

Is it possible to change the label of the right-down button (OK-Button) in the default android-keyboard? I want to set my own text on it and I have tried the following code:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findviewById(...);
et.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
et.setImeActionLabel("myLabel", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

However, the Label I see on the Button is the default from `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` namely "OK". Should I adapt propely the above code, or is there another way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Otherwise the EditText defaults to `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE`, which always has the "enter as line break" key instead of `IME_ACTION_DONE`.